# Laravel Caching User related caching

Tags: mysql, laravel, caching, laravel-5.1

Lets say i have a system where i have 3 models manufacturer, vehicles and Brand.

```
Vehicles -> One to one -> brand / manufacturer
Manufacturer -> One to many -> brand / vehicles
Brand -> One to many -> Vehicles
Brand -> One to One  -> Manufacturer
```

The system has an admin panel and a user panel.

**Admin Panel:**

In the admin panel i usually do something like this

```
Vehicle::with('manufacturer', 'brand')->get();
```

I also dont cache this query, and i think its fine as i dont need much speed in the admin area.

**User Area:**

But in the user area, i use much simpler queries as i have read that simpler queries are better as they can be cached. So i use one query to get manufacturer of a vehicle and another query to get brand of the vehicle. Then i just prepare an array to send to the view. Here is a sample query

```
Manufacturer::where('vehicle_id', $vehicleID)->where('is_active', 1)->get($columns);
```

every users will have different vehicles. Lets say **user A** has 10 vehicles and **user B** has 20 vehicles.

**So my question is how can i cache user specific queries, that are changing constantly?**

**Secondly is there any any reliable but automated way of doing this instead of changing the code, something like memcache or similar?**

I have also heard about redis caching, i think it grabs all the data from mysql and then stores in redis and next time it just fetches it from redis instead of mysql. Is this better? and can i do this without changing much code?

NOTE: One more thing to keep in mind is that this system has to be auto scalable, i.e used on aws beanstalk or something similar so the databases should be synced. Dont know yet how the synching works.

As always, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to cache results.  Cache::put('user' . $userID, $result, env('CACHE_TIME'));

Comment: No i didn't, as i have no idea which cache system i should use. Secondly the data is constantly changing. Let say some one buys a vehicle in the next 30 seconds, How do you handle something like this?

Comment: I will make an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**code example.**

```
$result = {your result} 

if (!Cache::has('user' . $userID) || env('CACHE_TIME') < 0) {
    Cache::put('user' . $userID, $result, env('CACHE_TIME'));
} else {
    $result = Cache::get('user' . $userID);
}
```

**.env file**

```
CACHE_TIME = 240 // cache time minutes, you can disable cache with -1
CACHE_DRIVER=file
```

**after user buy a vehicle**

```
Cache::forget('user' . $userID);
```

*Note: you can change cache method. More info at https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/cache*

Comment: I really like this idea, its simple yet very powerful. The only concerns that i do have is that if i use a file based cache driver, how will it react to automatic scaling, (where there might be 3 cloned servers running the same scripts) ?

Comment: I couldn't try redis with laravel but i think you can use to pass scaling problems.

Comment: will look into that. Thanks, Gorkem